# Generate Report Of Completed Work Using Org-Mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would simply like to generate a report of all of the TODO items that I completed today using org-mode. Ideally the report would look a lot like the weekly agenda, except instead of displaying active TODO's it would display the TODO's that I completed per day. I've tried using the agenda search but I only see non-complete TODO's.

This seems like something that would be really simple but I just haven't been able to find any docs on it.

Comment: Are you using time tracking? Do you have `org-log-done` enabled?

Comment: I don't but all of my CLOSED tasks are timestamped, so it must be turned on by default in my version of org-mode. However, I think I figured it out after looking up the docs on that property and I'll update this later. Thanks!

Comment: You're right erikstokes. Thanks!